# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" in command line procedure

Tags: genexus

I am consuming an API via &httpclient.
Running a command line procedure I am getting the following error:

"System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

I am using, Genexus 17, c#
If I run it from the web via a Web Pannel, it works without problems, but if I run it from a command line procedure, it doesn't work.
This if it were web is solved by configuring in the web.config:

but since the process is command line, where should I configure to raise the error that I am receiving?